# i want to send people straight to the translated version of my website

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation, geotargetting

Hey Everyone hopes you are all doing well need your suggestion..
my website is based in Spain all I want if someone visits sites from Spain website open in Spanish language and 2nd if someone opens from France language is french and for the rest of the counties language should be English..i found a plugin called geotargeting but its too much expensive

Comment: Which translation plugin do you use?

Comment: at that moment im using Gtranslate plugin but using this plugin user needs to select a language whenever he comes on my website Im looking for based on IP detect for spain and France

Comment: Gtranslate says in their description: "Auto-switch language based on browser defined language". Wouldn't this help?

Answer (score 0):

Simplest of the solution is to present the website in English (or the language you get most visitors) and ask the visitors to select the language by themselves based on their priority. But if you have no choice but to redirect them, then either create your own plugin or use that is already there. You can try plugins like [IP2Location Redirection](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ip2location-redirection/) or [WPML automatic language with GeoIP](https://github.com/ocReaper/wpml-automatic-language-with-geoip).